# ¿Como puedo hacer que el código de un slider que funcione para 3 sliders?

Tags: javascript, optimizar

quiero hacer un código bien optimizado(para que no me ocupe mucho espacio en el js) con js vanilla y tengo 3 sliders independientes pero que se repite mucho el código ¿como puedo hacer para que el slider funcione en los 3 ocupando solo un codigo? mi idea era algo así como se hace en css .active__1, .demo__1:hover, .active__2, .demo__2:hover, .active__3, .demo__3:hover { opacity: 1;} pero con las  variables de js
todo esto lo quería hacer con un document.getElementsByCLassName o con querySelectorAll ¿se pueden agregar varias clases al mismo tiempo con una sola variable?

```js
//SLIDER"1
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function slider()  {
  


   let indice1 = 1;
     muestrario1( indice1 );
        
function avanzarFoto1(n1){
    muestrario1( indice1+=n1 );
}
    
 function posicion1(n1){
     muestrario1( indice1=n1 );
 }
 setInterval(function tiempo1(){
          muestrario1( indice1+=1 )
 },3000);
 function muestrario1(n1){
     let ite1;
     let imagenes1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-img__1, slider-img__2');
     let controlNavImgs1 = document.getElementsByClassName('li-control-nav__1,');
 
     if(n1 > imagenes1.length ){
         indice1 = 1;
     }
     if(n1 < 1){
         indice1 = imagenes1.length;
     }
     for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < imagenes1.length ; ite1++){
         imagenes1[ite1].style.display = 'none';
     }
     for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < controlNavImgs1.length ; ite1++){
         controlNavImgs1[ite1].className = controlNavImgs1[ite1].className.replace(" active", "");
     }
 
     imagenes1 [indice1-1].style.display = ' block';
     controlNavImgs1[indice1 -1].className += ' active';
     
 }
      
  

})  
//lightbox


function openModal1() {
    document.getElementById("the-modal__1").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  function closeModal1() {
    document.getElementById("the-modal__1").style.display = "none";
   
    
  }
  
  let lightboxIndex1 = 1;
  showSlides1(lightboxIndex1);
  
  function plusSlides1(num1) {
    showSlides1(lightboxIndex1 += num1);
  }
  
  function currentSlides1(num1) {
    showSlides1(lightboxIndex1 = num1);
  }
  
  function showSlides1(num1) {
    let it1;
    let slides1 = document.getElementsByClassName("light-slides__1");
    let dots1 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo__1")
   /* let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");*/
    if (num1 > slides1.length) {lightboxIndex1 = 1}
    if (num1 < 1) {lightboxIndex1 = slides1.length}
    for (it1 = 0; it1 < slides1.length; it1++) {
        slides1[it1].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (it1 = 0; it1 < dots1.length; it1++) {
        dots1[it1].className = dots1[it1].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides1[lightboxIndex1-1].style.display = "block";
    dots1[lightboxIndex1-1].className += " active";
  /*  captionText.innerHTML = dots[lightboxIndex1-1].alt;*/
  }
```

```html
 <div id="box-slider__3"   >
    <ul id="lista-slider__3" >
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__1" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__1__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA1__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(1)" class="img-items__3"></div></li> 
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__2" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__2__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA2__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(2)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__3" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__3__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA3__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(3)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__4" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__4__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA4__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(4)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__5" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__5__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA5__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(5)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__6" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__6__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA6__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(6)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__7" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__7__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA7__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(7)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__8" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__8__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA8__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(8)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__9" ><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__9__3"> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA9__3.jpg"  alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(9)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__10"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__10__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA10__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(10)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__11"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__11__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA11__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(11)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__12"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__12__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA12__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(12)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__13"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__13__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA13__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(13)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__14"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__14__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA14__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(14)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__15"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__15__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA15__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(15)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__16"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__16__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA16__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(16)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__17"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__17__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA17__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(17)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__18"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__18__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA18__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(18)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__19"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__19__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA19__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(19)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>
 <li class="slider-items__3" id="img-slider__20"><div class="slider-img__3" id="boxinbox-slider__20__3"><img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA20__3.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(20)" class="img-items__3"></div></li>


<!--**************************************************SLIDER-CONTROLS-NAV 3*********************************************************-->
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(1)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(2)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(3)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(4)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(5)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(6)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(7)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(8)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(9)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__1 " onclick="posicion3(10)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(11)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(12)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(13)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(14)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(15)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(16)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(17)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(18)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(19)"></li>
          <li class="li-control-nav__3 slider-none__3__2" onclick="posicion3(20)"></li>
 
        </ol>
    
<div id="the-modal__3" class="modal__3">
  <span class="button-close__3 cursor" onclick="closeModal3()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content__3">

<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >1 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA1__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li> 
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >2 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA2__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >3 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA3__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >4 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA4__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >5 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA5__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >6 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA6__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >7 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA7__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >8 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA8__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >9 / 91  <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA9__3.png"  alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >10 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA10__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >11 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA11__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >12 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA12__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >13 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA13__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >14 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA14__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >15 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA15__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >16 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA16__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >17 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA17__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >18 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA18__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >19 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA19__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>
<li class="light-slides__3" ><div class="lightMarker__3" >20 / 91 <img src="/sources/slider automatico 3/img-SA20__3.png" alt="" ></div></li>


<a class="prev__3" onclick="plusSlides3(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next__3" onclick="plusSlides3(1)">&#10095;</a>
<!--**************************************************lightbox*********************************************************-->
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(1) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(2) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(3) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(4) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(5) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(6) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(7) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(8) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(9) "></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(10)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(11)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(12)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(13)"></span></div> 
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(14)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(15)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(16)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(17)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(18)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(19)"></span></div>
<div class="column__3"><span class="demo__3"   onclick="openModal3();currentSlides3(20)"></span></div>


      </div>
<!--*********************************************lightbox******************************************-->
```

Comment: Puedes hacer una función a la que le asignas parámetros y que cree el slider solo cambiando los parámetros y llamándolo con una sola línea luego donde tu quieras.

Comment: @JeanGotopo O sea basicamente como esta y con los parametros que cambien el número 1 que yo le puse? como ite[2]

Comment: Probablemente te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/437338/54039), aunque el código Javascript es completamente diferente y deberás adaptar el HTML.